# RabbitMQ for Java: how to send multiple float values?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

New to RabbitMQ and message passing APIs. I want to send a triplet of float values every few milliseconds. To initialize my connection/channel, I have:

```
connection = factory.newConnection();
channel = connection.createChannel();
channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
```

Then when I want to send a message, the following does strings:

```
private void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
}
```

How can I change `sendMessage` to send `float x1, float x2, float x3` ?

And on the server-side, how would I receive/parse this message into 3 floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, for instance, use a `ByteBuffer`:

```
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(12)  // 3 floats
    .putFloat(f1).putFloat(f2).putFloat(f3);    // put them; .put*() return this
channel.basicPublish(buf.array());              // send
```

This will write the floats in big endian (default network order and what Java uses as well).

On the receiving side, you would do:

```
// delivery is a QueuingConsumer.Delivery
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(delivery.getBody());
final float f1 = buf.getFloat();
final float f2 = buf.getFloat();
final float f3 = buf.getFloat();
```

Comment: Hey that's awesome. What's QueuingConsumer.Delivery?

Comment: The receiving side of a RabbitMQ client -- I have gone and read the tutorial :p (ie, [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html))

Comment: Cool. One more issue - in my code for channel.basicPublish I get the error: `The method basicPublish(String, String, AMQP.BasicProperties, byte[]) in the type Channel is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])` EDIT - nvm, I seem to have fixed (compiled at least) with `channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, buf.array()); `