# RabbitMQ for Java: how to send multiple values?

Tags: java, c#, json, rabbitmq

This is an extension on [RabbitMQ for Java: how to send multiple float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600563/rabbitmq-for-java-how-to-send-multiple-float-values)

Instead of 3 float parameters, I want to send 3 different classes as parameters and I want to use the JSon protocol.

The server is written in C#. Hence I decode the JSon string method of the server side.

Basically the solution offered on the other post in terms of floats is as follows:

```
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(12)  // 3 floats
    .putFloat(f1).putFloat(f2).putFloat(f3);    // put them; .put*() return this
channel.basicPublish(buf.array());              // send
```

This will write the floats in big endian (default network order and what Java uses as well).

On the receiving side, you would do:

```
// delivery is a QueuingConsumer.Delivery

final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(delivery.getBody());
final float f1 = buf.getFloat();
final float f2 = buf.getFloat();
final float f3 = buf.getFloat();
```

but **I want to send class Car, Airplane, Boat as JSon formatted from Java to C#**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume Car, Airplane and Boat are simple [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) classes and their field members  map the json contract.

You could use a json codec to serialize your objects into JSON. For example you can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Classes:

```
class Car {
    private String model;
    public String getModel(){};
    public void setModel(String model){...};            
}
class Airplane {
    private String model;
    public String getModel(){};
    public void setModel(String model){...};            
}
class Boat {
    private String model;
    public String getModel(){};
    public void setModel(String model){...};            
}
```

The example will use Jackson and will output a structure like that: 
`{"car":{"model":"xxx"},"boat":{"model":"xxx"}, ,"airplane":{"model":"xxx"}}`

```
// Create the jsonFactory with an object mapper to serialize object to json
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory(new ObjectMapper());

// Create the byte array output stream
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// Create the json generator 
JsonGenerator generator = jsonFactory.createGenerator(outputStream);

// Write the start object, ie. {}
generator.writeStartObject();
// Write the car "car":{}
generator.writeObjectField("car" , car);
// Write the car "boat":{}
generator.writeObjectField("boat" , boat);
// Write the car "airplane":{}
generator.writeObjectField("airplane" , airplane);
// Close the object
generator.writeEndObject();
// And the generator
generator.close();

// Convert the byte array stream to a byte array and publish the message
channel.basicPublish(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

If you have a JavaBeans or a map which wraps theses 3 classes the code may be simplier:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
byte[] bur = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(wrapper);
channel.basicPublish(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

Finally on the c# side you should create the same class and [deserialize them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c).

You could use some json to java/c# generator, eg. [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).